# SimpleCV colour correction for under or overexposed photos

Tags: python, simplecv

Was wondering whether anyone know how to do the following in SimpleCV. I would like to colour correct a photo, so that if it's under or over exposed it is corrected. I believe cameras do this by taking an average of the colours and then adjusting the colours to turn the average into a 50% grey. This simple method should work ok for my scenario.

If anyone has some example Python code to do this or something more complex it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function built into SimpleCV:

```
balanced_img = Image('myphoto.jpg').whiteBalance('GrayWorld') # 'Simple' or 'GrayWorld'
```

You can read about the white balance methods from links in the [SimpleCV docs for whiteBalance](http://simplecv.org/docs/SimpleCV.html#i/SimpleCV.ImageClass.Image/whiteBalance)

This does what you described you wanted - adjust the average to a gray-scale.  The 'Simple' method basically stretches the color range for each channel from 0 - 255 after clipping some of the outliers.

You can also do color correction with functions like [applyRGBCurve](http://simplecv.org/docs/SimpleCV.html#i/SimpleCV.ImageClass.Image/applyRGBCurve).